# What ways will the tags in the head be lessen if if i have hundreds of pages?

Tags: html

Head tag of **index.php**

```
<head>
   <title>Ephemaire</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive-style.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/logo/favicon.png">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- MinBootstrap -->
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!-- Bootstrap -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery -->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.parallax.js"></script> <!-- jQuery Parallax -->
   <script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script> <!-- jQuery NiceScroll -->
   <script src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script> <!-- jQuery Stick Menu -->
   <script src="js/script.js"></script> <!-- All script -->
</head>
```

I have a header, a side bar, and a footer and they are in a separate file. So that in the index, I will just have to call the php file using the `<?php include 'header.php'; ?>` and so on and so forth for the side bar and a footer. In those 3 files, I didnt have to add the tags html, head, body because they are called in index.php.

In the sidebar, I have links such as Products, Policy, About and Contact Us.
The format of the site is just simple. However, in the pages products, policy, about and contact us, I have to copy all the codes from the html tag down to the body tag and replace the content for about us, or products.
The question is, if I have a hundred of pages, I think that this method copying is not a good move. Is there any alternative with this?

Comment: So if I understand the layout of about us, is exactly the same as all other pages?

Comment: @Sanderbakker the layout is just the same to all pages. The difference is just the content of each page. The header, the sidebar and footer of the page remains the same.

Comment: You are probably looking for something that supports https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/twoStepView.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by putting the header, sidebar, and footer in a separete file.

For example files like:

- header.php
- footer.php
- sidebar.php

These files will include the layout of your header, sidebar and footer. By doing this you won't have to copy the content all the into a new file but you can simply include it in your file by calling:

```
include ('footer.php'); 
include ('sidebar.php');
include ('header.php');
```

If you have any questions, please ask them!

Comment: i write in my post that footer, sidebar and header are in a separate file. What im asking is the pages on the sidebar. I keep on copying all the codes in the head tag on all pages on the sidebar.